# Remove object if empty list inside it in Python

Tags: python

I have a json file with objects with the same ID. I have a `results` list inside each. How to remove the entire object if `results == []` ?
I have a And I have a `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'item' referenced before assignment` error.

JSON input:

```
[{
    "objectID": 10745,
    "results": [
    {
        "model": "AUDI - TT QUATTRO",
        "price_str": "4 800 €"
        }]
    },
 {
    "objectID": 10745,
    "results": []
    }
]
```

My code:

```
for item in data:
    objectId = item["objectID"]
    results = item["results"]

    def removeDuplicate():
        if not results:
            del item
    removeDuplicate()
```

The expected output:

```
[{
    "objectID": 10745,
    "results": [
    {
        "model": "AUDI - TT QUATTRO",
        "price_str": "4 800 €"
         }]
    }
]
```

Comment: Read [short-description-of-the-scoping-rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules) to get the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting items from a list while iterating the same list is likely to cause trouble.  Try constructing a new list instead with filtering logic to remove the unwanted items:

```
new_data = [item for item in data if item['results']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter on the list of dictionaries based on the dicts value for "results":

```
data = [{
    "objectID": 10745,
    "results": [
    {
        "model": "AUDI - TT QUATTRO",
        "price_str": "4 800 EUR"
    }]
    },
    {
    "objectID": 10745,
    "results": []
    }
]

cleared = [i for i in data if i.get("results")] 

print(cleared)
```

Output:

```
[{'objectID': 10745, 
  'results': [{'model': 'AUDI - TT QUATTRO', 'price_str': '4 800 EUR'}]}]
```

If no `"results"`in the dict `.get()` will return `None` - if present and empty it is `falsy` as well (`None` and empty lists are) and it will not land inside `cleared`.

Regarding your error a good read of [short-description-of-the-scoping-rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules) should help you get the error message: your `item` is not declared inside your functions scope and python does not allow you to use the `item` from the for loop.