# Check if key value is the same in a dict in python

Tags: python

I asked how to remove an object when a list inside it was empty in this question ([Remove object if empty list inside it in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61526868/remove-object-if-empty-list-inside-it-in-python/61526999#61526999)).
The problem is that I'd like to do this only when the `objectId` value is the same. I have others objects with different ids and I don't want to touch it.

Input:

```
data = [{
"objectID": 10745,
"results": [
{
    "model": "AUDI - TT QUATTRO",
    "price_str": "4 800 EUR"
}]
},
{
"objectID": 10745,
"results": []
},
"objectID": 10746,
"results": [
{
    "model": "Porsche 911",
    "price_str": "48 000 EUR"
}]
},
```

]

My code:

```
for item in data:
        objectId = item["objectID"]
        results = item["results"]

        def removeDuplicate():
            #if objectid are the same
            new_data = [item for item in data if item['results']]
            data[:] = new_data
        removeDuplicate()
```

Expected output:

```
    [{'objectID': 10745, 
  'results': [{'model': 'AUDI - TT QUATTRO', 'price_str': '4 800 EUR'}]}, {'objectID': 10746, 
  'results': [{'model': 'Porsche 911', 'price_str': '48 000 EUR'}]}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although maybe not fast,but short.

```
data = [{
        "objectID": 10745,
        "results": [{
            "model": "AUDI - TT QUATTRO",
            "price_str": "4 800 EUR"
        }]
    },
    {
        "objectID": 10745,
        "results": []
    },
    {
        "objectID": 10746,
        "results": [{
            "model": "Porsche 911",
            "price_str": "48 000 EUR"
        }]
    },
    { # add a test example
        "objectID": 10747,
        "results": []
    }
]
r = [d for i,d in enumerate(data) if d['objectID'] not in set(map(lambda x:x['objectID'],data[:i])) or d['results']]
print(r)
```

Result:

```
[{
    'objectID': 10745,
    'results': [{
        'model': 'AUDI - TT QUATTRO',
        'price_str': '4 800 EUR'
    }]
}, {
    'objectID': 10746,
    'results': [{
        'model': 'Porsche 911',
        'price_str': '48 000 EUR'
    }]
}, {
    'objectID': 10747,
    'results': []
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust your condition as:

```py
new_data = [item for item in data if item['results'] and objectId != item["objectID"]]
```

Comment: I I do this I only keep object with one `objectId` only no ? I want to target objects with the same id and then remove the ones with a empty `results` list

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby` but you will need to sort the data. I'd use `operator.itemgetter` for the key.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

data = [...]

osort = itemgetter('objectID')
sorted_data = sorted(data, key=osort)

output = [next(o for o in g if o['results']) for _, g in groupby(sorted_data, osort)]
```